# Are these style recognized by all browsers of all versions?

Tags: html, css

```
#parent div { float:right; }
#parent > div { float:right; }
```

Most importantly:**firefox** and **IE**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [chart](http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/):

`#parent > div` is supported by ALL browsers EXCEPT IE6.

Comment: … all browsers on that chart …

Comment: We do not like to mention Netscape 4. Let us pretend it never existed.

Answer (score 3):

No. Some browsers don't support CSS at all (lynx for example).

The glib answer aside, among browsers you probably care about, the child selector is not supported in Internet Explorer 6.

Comment: also the browsers that came out before CSS selectors were spec'd.

Comment: What about the first one?Is it supported by IE6?

Comment: Yes, IE6 supports descendant selectors.

Answer (score 0):

See [Quir}{smode](http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html)'s master compatibility table for answers to all these types of questions.

[Click here for the CSS Compatibility table](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)